# An integer between 1 and 1000 is chosen uniformly at random. Given that it is divisible by 4, what is the probability that it is divisible by 3?

Tags: probability

I've tried a couple different things for this problem. I know I am trying to find P[3|4].

First: P[3 and 4]/P[4] = (80/1000)/(250/1000)=.32. This wasn't right.

Second: (P[4|3]*P[3])/P[4] = ((80/1000)(333/1000))/(250/1000)=.10656 and this wasn't right.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If it is divisible by 3,4, then it is divisible by $3 \times 4$

Comment: I got the correct answer. It is (83/1000)/(250/1000)=.332 since 1000/12 is about 83. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that if a number is divisible by $3$, and by $4$, then it is divisible by $3\times 4$. Then, out of all $250$ numbers that are divisible by $4$, how many are divisible by $12$?

Answer (score 1):

83 numbers are divisible by 4 and 3 both, $[1000/12] = 83$

You already have selected 250 numbers

so probability that number is also divisible by 3 is

$$\frac{83}{250}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a generalization: Let $A$ be the set of numbers divisible by $4$ and $B$ the set of numbers divisible by $3$. What you want is $P(B|A)$. By the definition of joint probability $P(B|A)=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$.

You know that $P(A \cap B)$ is the set of numbers that are divisible by both $3$ and $4$, hence this is the set divisible by multiples of $12$, $|A \cap B|=83$ and $|B|=250$, therefore $P(B|A)=\frac{83}{250}$